# What is the earliest hook comment meta can be saved?

Tags: comments

I'm trying to integrate a new security checker service into WordPress comments. My goal is to tell the service's api to scan all links in a comment.

My question is: what is the earliest (or most proper) hook to use to add comment meta keeping in mind that the goal is to automatically mark comments as spam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source for [`wp_new_comment()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_new_comment/) there is `comment_post` action hook, which fires immediately after comment is inserted into database and so is probably what fits your needs.

However logically it's *after* decision if comment is spam or not, I am not sure how meta is involved in your case since approval status is not natively meta field.